# MongoDB - Cannot search between 2 different months with format d/m/Y h:m

Tags: php, mongodb, aggregation

I have a problem finding data by date and the date format is automatically saved as "d/m/Y h:m" and I don't understand why I can't search when the month is different and I have some data like

```
[
 {
   id: 1,
   ships: [
    {
     date: "11/11/2023 07:00"
    }
  ]
 },
 {
  id: 2,
  ships: [
   {
     date: "21/12/2023 07:00"
   }
  ]
 }
]
```

I tried the following but I can't search when the month is different. I'm using MongoDB's Aggregate.

```
$date = ['01/11/2023', '31/12/2023'];
$start = $date[0] ?? '';
$end   = $date[1] ?? '';
$defaultStart = new Date($start);
$defaultEnd = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($end));

if (strtotime($start) !== FALSE) {
    $start = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($start)) . ' 00:00';
}
if (strtotime($end) !== FALSE) {
    $end = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($end)) . ' 23:59';
}

$match = ['ships' => [
'$elemMatch' => [
    '$or' => [
        ['date' => [
            '$gte' => $start,
            '$lte' => $end
        ]],
        ['date' => [
            '$gte' => $defaultStart,
            '$lte' => $defaultEnd
        ]]
    ]
  ]
]]
```

Comment: It seems you are storing the date in MongoDB as string instead of date/timestamp type. This will result in the query is not working when you are using *compare* operator like `$lt` and etc. You should store it as date/timestamp type instead. Otherwise, you need to take the additional step to convert those date string into date type and compare.

Comment: So i believe you cannot use greater or lesser equals on a string, you would have to convert your date filed in mongodb from string to date, or else you need to filter out the results on the server.